# finding the order of the element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: whats the order of the element a=33 in Z60 (under modular addition)?

Answer: $\langle 33 \rangle= \{33,6,39,12,45,18,51,24,57,30,3,36,9,42,15,48,21,54,27,0,\}$. Therefore, $\text{order}(33)=20$

Whats the inverse of $33$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ (under modular addition)?

Im struggling with finding the inverse. Can anyone show me how to find it?

I would deeply appreciate your work and efforts

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** From your previous work, we know that:
$$
0 = \underbrace{33 + 33 + \cdots + 33}_{20 \text{ times}} = 33 + \underbrace{33 + \cdots + 33}_{19 \text{ times}}
$$
Thus, we know that the inverse of $33$ is:
$$
\underbrace{33 + \cdots + 33}_{19 \text{ times}}
$$
Incidentally, this is just $60 - 33$.

Comment: Is there another way to show that it's 27? Im trying to understand the concept of the inverse in this case. Could you explain how you found the inverse of it?

Comment: The opposite of addition is subtraction. So the inverse of $33$ is $-33$. But since $-33$ isn't in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,59\}$, we have to take this number modulo $60$ by adding $60$ to get $-33 + 60 = 27$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compute all the multiples. You know that the order of $33$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that
$$
n\cdot33\equiv 0\pmod{60}
$$
that is, the least positive integer such that $33n$ is a multiple of $60$ or, equivalently, $11n$ is a multiple of $20$. Thus $n=20$.

For the inverse (I'd use “opposite”, but it's a matter of conventions), you want an integer $m$ such that $33+m\equiv0\pmod{60}$. Of course an integer $m$ such that $33+m=60$ is good.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of $33$ in this additive group is $-33$, but in $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$, we have $-33\equiv 27\pmod{60}$